# Older browser compatibility with using the DOM to change element styles?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, browser, compatibility

I've checked http://caniuse.com and MDN, but didnt get conclusive answers. MDN says `document.getElementByID` is supported since older browsers but not sure if the `.style` property is included in that support when doing this:

```js
document.getElementByID('changeStyle').style.color = 'yellow'
```

This makes me worry that the element might not change the style after triggering the event.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: [`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) is a property of the HTMLElement object, which is unrelated to `getElementById()`. To answer your question, yes `style` is entirely safe to use, and has been for [literally decades](https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_style). However I would argue its use implies that you're putting CSS styling in to the JS logic which should be avoided where possible. Add/remove/toggle  a class instead

Comment: How old browser are you trying to target? Mosaic 1.0?

Comment: Also, `document.getElementByID()` is invalid. JS is case-sensitive so it should be `document.getElementById()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thanks, that cleared up alot.